# How to covert async call to work as sync call in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm a newbie in C#, and I'm going to develop a small program using a third party network library to send the requests.

Suppose there have some requests (just simple strings) stored in the queue `qTasks`, and it will handle those requests one by one with the order as submitted, the queue can be updated during execution, and it should be stopped whenever there has error returned.

I can just use a for loop to call the send request command in the array one by one, but unfortunately the `sendrequest` command is an async method with callback `OnStageChanged`, and I need to check the result before sending the next request when the status is "Done".

I'm now using the following method to handle it:

In the main UI Thread,

```
// Put those request text in a queue names qTasks, then call a goNextTask() to process the request one by one.
// The queue can be updated by the UI thread at anytime, goNextTask will be called periodically to handle those pending request in the queue.

private void goNextTask(bool lastSuccess = true)
{
    if (lastSuccess) 
    {
        if (qTasks.Count > 0) 
        {
            // continue to next request
            string requestText = qTasks.Dequeue();
            SendRequest(requestText, OnStageChangeHandler);
        } else {
            // Report for all request sent successfully
        }
    } else {
        // stop and show error
    }
}
```

The callback method `OnStageChangeHandler` will be called by the library whenever the stage changes, and it will have state "Done" when completed.

```
private void OnStageChangeHandler(object sender, StageChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.newState == SessionStates.Done)
    {
        // check result here
        bool success = <...> 

        // then call the goNextTask in UI thread with the result of current request.
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
           System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
          (Action)(() => goNextTask(success)));
    }
}
```

Although it works fine now, I think it's a little bit stupid as it has a somewhat recursive flow (A -> B -> A -> B ->....).

I learnt that MS has improved the web request handling, so that it can work in sync mode.

I'd like to know if I can have a wrapper to make the above async call work as a sync call, so that it can be done in a simple flow as a loop like that:

```
while (qTaks.Count > 0) 
{
    if (!sendAndWaitReturn(qTasks.Dequeue())) {
        // Report error and quit
    }
}
// all tasks completed
```

This `sendAndWaitReturn` method will send the request, then wait for the status "Done", and then return the result.

I found some example that may use a control flag to indicate the status of the current request, and the callback function will update this control flag, while the UI thread will loop on this flag using a while loop:

```
while (!requestDone);
```

so that it will not continue to `nextRequest` until `requestDone`. But in this case, the UI will be blocked.

Is there any better way to convert the async call to work as a sync call without blocking the UI thread?

Comment: Can you give an example on whats being processed on the SendRequest method ? Recursion is the best way to do this. But, based on the logic we can change the way its written.

Comment: The SendRequest method is provided by the library.  In fact, it's the FiddlerCore's SendRequest method, the required headers and requestBodyBytes is generated from the data in the queue.

Comment: What, if anything does `SendRequest` return? Does it return a `Task`? But even if you do make this synchronous, you do understand that doing this on the UI thread will freeze the UI?

Comment: SendRequest return the session object, but I don't need this one, as it will also be available in the OnStageChangeHandler as the input parameter.   As mentioned in my post, I found some way to use the while loop keep checking on a control flag, the UI will be frozen.  So, I'd like to know if there has any other better way which will not block the UI thread.   I just want to see if it can simplify the program flow and make it looks like a sync call.

Comment: Just learnt from msdn that there has a WaitHandle for signaling, Instead of using a while loop on a control flag which introduce blocking on UI Thread, it may use WaitHandle to wait for the signal.   I found some examples but all used for waiting in background thread, I just wonder if it could it be used for waiting in UI thread?  i.e. after sendRequest, the UI thread start WaitOne, and the OnStageChangeHandler will set the signal once "Done".  Would it be better?  Maybe I can try it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty you're going to run into is you have conflicting desires. On one hand, you want to avoid blocking the UI thread. On the other hand, you don't want to run things asynchronously and so you're going to block the UI thread.

You're going to have to pick one, and there's absolutely no reason to keep on doing things synchronously (especially in light of blocking the UI thread). If it hurts when you do that, *don't do that.*

You haven't specified, but I'm guessing that you're starting this processing from a button click event. Make the method invoked by that click event async. For example:

```
private async void StartProcessing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(() => StartProcessing());
}
```

There, you've started processing and the UI thread isn't tied up.

The next thing is that, you're right, having the event behave in that cyclical manner is silly. The event is to notify someone that the state has changed, its goal isn't to manage queue policy. The *queue* should manage queue policy (or if you'd rather not abstract that out, the *method that processes requests*).

So how would you do that? Well, you've said that SendRequest hands the session object back to the caller. The caller is presumably the one who is orchestrating queue policy and determining whether or not to call SendRequest again.

Have the caller check the session object for validity and decide whether to keep going based on that.

Additionally, I'm unfamiliar with that particular library, but briefly glancing at the documentation it looks like there's also a SendRequestAndWait() method with the same signature and that sounds like it might better meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the advice.

In fact, the send request process can be triggered by UI button or timer event.  There have other processes running together in the application, and they will submit the request to the request queue on some particular event (e.g. after completion of calculation process).  Besides, user can also add the request directly in the UI, that's why I don't want to block the UI when sending request.   The send request process will then submit those request in the queue in pre-defined period or triggered by button click in UI.

Comment: The SendRequestAndWait method sound like what I'm looking for.  But I'm not sure if SendRequestAndWait method will really wait until "done", as it also has the callback for OnStageChange, it seems that it still using the callback method to notify caller, but the help file has no detail on it.  Maybe I will try it later.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just tested, the SendRequestAndWait really works.  Although it still using the callback to notify the caller, but it will wait until status "done".  I have checked with debugger, it will finish the OnStageChangeHandler with status "Done" before executing to next statement.  Thanks.